# SSH asks for password but I can get in thru serial port without it

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, password, root

I have an arm7 board running GNU/Linux, it's connected to the internet via Ethernet port. I am trying to SSH in to it as root@IPaddr but it is prompting me for a password. I am pretty sure the password was never set on it. I actually changed the sudoers file as well with :

> root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

but no use. I am able to shell in to it via serial port though without getting prompted for a password. I am a little lost.

```
root@mur0011:~# ls -la .ssh/
drwx------    2 root     root          4096 Nov  8 01:10 .
drwxr-xr-x   10 root     root          4096 Nov  8 01:10 ..
-rw-------    1 root     root          2347 Jun  1 21:20 authorized_keys
-rw-------    1 root     root          1675 May 31 23:19 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           397 May 31 23:19 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           803 Jun  1 19:51 known_hosts
root@mur0011:~# uname -a
Linux mur0011 3.14.38-6UL_ga+ge4944a5 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 14 16:48:19 
PDT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@mur0011:~# whoami
root
```

Comment: SSH and sudo permissions are not related - your root account probably has a default password set from when it was installed.

Comment: @l0b0 I am using PuTTY and serial interface lets me log in without a password but ssh does prompt for it. To make sure I tried
 sudo passwd -dl root 
[link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Re-disabling_your_root_account)
also , ssh -v generates the following error :
`Permission denied, please try again.`
`debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory`

Comment: some versions of `login(1)` look at a `securetty` file that may whitelist root access to the system without password, on the presumption that attackers do not have physical access to such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sshd` server will always ask for a password, unless you configure it to allow empty passwords.  Also, it most current default configurations, `sshd` is configured to disallow root logins or only allow root using public key authentication.

So, you should ensure that root can login through ssh and that empty passwords are allowed:

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PermitRootLogin yes
...
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
...
```

You will also need to set an empty root password.  This is not the same thing as no password.  No password is defined as either a non-existent password or an illegal password.  In either of these cases, an implicit, but impossible to enter, password will be required.  This, of course, means that `root` will not be able to login directly.  So, an `empty password` is what is required.

**Please note:**

This is very poor security and should only be used within a trusted network that is not directly accessible from the Internet.